# How can I quantify the number of swaps required for insertion sort?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Based on the Wikipedia implementation of insertion sort:

Given an input array $A$:

```
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
```

is there a way to quantify how many swaps are needed to sort the input list? It's $O(n^2)$, but I want a more precise bound. A perfectly sorted array clearly needs no swaps (so insertion sort is $\Omega(n)$), while a completely reversed array requires something on the order of $n^2$ swaps, but how do we quantify the number of swaps?

Comment: For what case? You just gave the number of swaps for a presorted array as $0$, and a reversed array takes $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = \frac{n\cdot (n-1)}{2}$ swaps. For anything in between there's probably a sequence that will require that number of swaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a classic exercise to relate the running time of insertion sort to the number of *inversions* in the input. An *inversion* is a pair of indices $i < j$ such that $A[i] > A[j]$. The number of comparisons made by insertion sort when there are $I$ inversions is always between $I$ and $I+n-1$.

Comment: Thanks! That's useful. Could you help me get started on relating the running time to num. of inversions? What's blocking me is that insertion sort isn't recursive, so we can't really start with a recurrence relation.

Comment: Where does the $+\; n -1$ come from? I would have expected that every inversion requires exactly one comparison to resolve.

Comment: @G.Bach The $n-1$ comes from the fact that at each iteration you always make at least one comparison. If you don't go all the way, then you have one extra comparison compared to the number of inversions. When you go all the way, you don't have this one extra, and that's why the bound is between $I$ and $I+n-1$.

Comment: @David There is no need to use a recurrence relation. Try to relate the length of the while loop for each $i$ to the number of inversions involving $i$.